# How can I catch this "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" error in my C program?

Tags: c, windows, runtime, exit, terminate

I have a C CLI program that crashes and generates this error in Windows 7:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

First, I read somewhere that it could be caused `assert` statements triggering so as a first measure I replaced them with if statements to catch and log any potential failed asserts. Second, I sprayed the code with `printf` statements to see where the program exits. Third, I especially made sure that the code doesn't exit anywhere without first logging the exit. The program is threaded so there are quite a few things going on, but nothing too complex.

Now the problem is that the second time I got the error it showed that the program exited outside of my `printf` statements so I can't tell where it exited.

So two questions:

1. I suspect I would need to use a proper debugger to see more details regarding the exit, if so, which one?
2. Are there any other gotchas regarding this sort of error besides the `assert` statements? I find quite a few `C++` blog entries regarding this error, but not too many `C` ones.

I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. Also, I am invoking the program in `CMD.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you removed calls to `assert` which are typically meant to help track down cases where the assumption the programmer makes don't hold? Really? Uhm...

Second of all, are you familiar with the debugger at all? Visual C++ should include an integrated debugger that can, when your program runs in debug mode, not only show you where your process exits from but it can *also* show you exactly where your program crashes, how it got to that point and what the values of variables where at the time of the crash. Imagine that!

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) mostly talks about C# but the principles are the same.

Comment: I replaced the `assert` statements with regular if statements where I could deal with the assert and log it. And no, I am not very familiar with the debugging in Visual C++ imagine that.

Comment: Rather than messing with `assert`, run your program inside the debugger. You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is from the VC runtime.  It happens when an exception is thrown and not caught anywhere.

Compile your program with a debugging debugging configuration (that should be the default) and run in the debugger, and when you hit an unhandled exception, the debugger will break.  Under the "Debug" menu, you will find an "Exceptions" item, which will help you fine tune how the debugger responds to exceptions.

Note that in the context of C++ and Windows, 'exception' can mean one of several things; there are the Win32 exceptions, the C++ exception, and VS Structured Exception Handling.

assertions are for fail conditions that you never expect to happen, but can't prove can't happen.  You should always be surprised by an assertion.  Many (most? all?) implementations of assert() are only compiled in debug configurations and not release configurations.

Comment: It seems the VC debugger is the way to go. How will performance be affected by running the program in the debugger?

Comment: It will run slower.  Don't bother optimizing a program that isn't correct--solve the problem in front of you.

Comment: That's very true. In this particular case however I suspect the crash is performance related. That is, if it runs slower the crash might not materialize... Thanks anyways for your help, much appreciated.